# Управление процессами C++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux

Пытаюсь написать программу ,которая управляет некоторым количеством процессов и следит за ними,а конкретно,если убиваем процесс,то возобновляем его.Не понимаю почему всегда срабатывает обработчик signal_handler,хотя даже не убиваю сигнал.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <signal.h>
    #include <csignal>
    #include "process.h"
    using namespace std;

    int N=0;

    void signal_handler(int signal)//обработчик сигнала
    {
        if (signal==SIGCHLD)
        {
            cout<<"SIGCHLD received"<<endl;
        }

    }
    void Create_Processes()//функция создания процессов
    {
        cout<<"Create Process "<<endl;
        cout<<"Input count of processes"<<endl;
        cin>>N;
        pid.resize(N);
        my_pid.resize(N);
        my_pa_pid.resize(N);

        for (int i=1;i<=N;i++)
        {
            pid[i]=fork();
            my_pid[i]=getpid();
            my_pa_pid[i]=getppid();

            if (pid[i]==-1) cout <<"Error"<<endl;
            else if (pid[i]==0)
            {
                //children
                //for(;;);
                cout<<"pid["<<i<<"]="<<"(CHILDREN)   I am Children! and my pid is  "<<my_pid[i]<<" and my parent pid is "<<my_pa_pid[i]<<endl;

            }
            else {
                //parent

                cout<<"pid["<<i<<"]="<<" (PARENT)  I am main process and  my pid is "<<my_pid[i]<<" My process child "<<pid[i]<<endl;
                int child_status=0;
                signal(SIGCHLD,signal_handler);
                for (;;)
                {
                    pid[i]=waitpid(-1, &child_status, WNOHANG);
                    if (pid[i]>0)
                    {
                        pid[i]=fork();
                        cout<<"Resart process with pid "<<getpid()<<endl;
                        break;
                    }
                    pause();
                }


                }

            }


   int main() {

    Create_Processes();



        введите сюда код
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Так а что это вообще за феерический комбинаторный взрыв, в котором child процессы дальше еще порождают child процессы, а те порождают свои child процессы... И т.д. Это так и задумано?

Comment: И кто вам разрешил доступаться к `pid[N]`, `my_pid[N]`, `my_pa_pid[N]` после `pid.resize(N); my_pid.resize(N); my_pa_pid.resize(N);`? Вы не в курсе, что в С++ массивы индексируются с нуля?

Comment: есть же systemd и procd

Comment: Проблема решена ,спасибо.По поводу массивов(so close)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не понимаю почему всегда срабатывает обработчик signal_handler,хотя
>   даже не убиваю сигнал.

Сигнал SIGCHLD посылается родительскому процессу в тот момент, когда дочерний завершается. По **любой** причине - завершается. В частности, если дочерний процесс достиг *}* самого внешнего блока. Посмотрите на оператор *if* который определяет поведение дочернего процесса:

```
if (pid[i]==0) {
   cout<<"pid["<<i<<"]="<<"(CHILDREN)   I am Children! and my pid is  <<my_pid[i]<<" and my parent pid is "<<my_pa_pid[i]<<endl;
}
```

Т.е. дочерний процесс печатает сообщение и завершается. Родительскому, соответственно, посылается сигнал. Что Вас не устраивает ? То, что Вы не убиваете дочерние процессы? Так Вы просто не успеваете это сделать - они сами завершаются мгновенно.